# Command in FOR loop (How to get data I requested)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Yesterday I had seen question concerning how to get file space information. I tried command like this:

FOR /F %%A IN ('dir c:\ ^| findstr /rc:Adr') DO
echo A:"%%A"B:"%%B"C:"%%C"D:"%%D"

I thought it could be possible to extract last line, starting in my local language by "Adr", yours probably "Directory". It is not exactly the same because yesterday I got as output result the command itself: dir c:\ ^| findstr /rc:Adr. Now I test it again in CMD and got this:

```
C:\>FOR %A IN (dir c:\ ^| findstr /rc:Adr) Do Echo A:"%A"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>Echo A:"dir"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"
A:"dir"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>Echo A:"c:\"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"
A:"c:\"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>Echo A:"|"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"
A:"|"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>Echo A:"findstr"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"
A:"findstr"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>Echo A:"/rc:Adr"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"
A:"/rc:Adr"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>FOR %A IN ('dir c:\ ^| findstr /rc:Adr') Do Echo A:"%A"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>Echo A:"'dir"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"
A:"'dir"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>Echo A:"c:\"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"
A:"c:\"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>Echo A:"|"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"
A:"|"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>Echo A:"findstr"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"
A:"findstr"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>Echo A:"/rc:Adr'"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"
A:"/rc:Adr'"B:"%B"C:"%C"D:"%D"

C:\>dir c:\ | findstr /rc:Adr
           Adresářů:     6,   Volných bajtů:  1 447 161 856

C:\>
```

Next situation that I have problem with:
If I want to print filenames:

```
@Echo off
FOR  %%F IN (dir *.inf) DO (
echo %%F
)
```

First item in the output is dir and then the files. What I do wrong not to obtain the command itself, but the data I requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate through lines returned by another command you need to use for command with /f switch. Take a look at `for /?` for detailed information.

To obtain the amount of free disk space on a computer with Chech version of Windows, use:

`for /f "tokens=4,*" %%A in ('dir c:\ ^| findstr /rc:Adr') do echo %%B`

If you want a language-independant solution, use:

```
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic volume where "DriveLetter='C:'" get FreeSpace /value') do echo %%A
```

In the second case, you can omit the dir command and iterate through files directly:

`for %%A in (*.inf) do echo %%A`